# Active Directory Account keeps getting disabled

Tags: active-directory

My account keeps getting lockout. Then I wait 15 min for it to automatically reset. My IT department says there is something on my machine that is continually trying to login with bad credentials. Is there a way to determine the offending app or service? Like a monitor or logger?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I would look through your Add\Remove Programs if nothing in there looks like the culprit, I would consider that you may have malware on your PC. have IT replace it or wipe it and restore you data.

Comment: It would have to be something where you specified your password and has not been updated since your last password change. Maybe a scheduled task?